# Show that the minimal polynomial $f(x) $ has $\deg f(x)=5$

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Let $V,W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces over $\Bbb R$ and let $T_1:V\to V$ and $T_2:W\to W$ be linear transformations whose minimal polynomial are given by $f_1(x)=x^3+x^2+x+1$ and $f_2(x)=x^4-x^2-2$.

Let $T:V \oplus W \to V\oplus W  $ be the linear transformation defined by

$T(v,w)=(T_1(v),T_2(w))$ for $(v,w)\in V\oplus W$ and let $f(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $T$.

Then

> Show that $\text{nullity} (T)=0$ and $\deg f(x)=5$

**My try**:

Let $(x,y)\in \ker (V\oplus W)\implies T(v,w)=0\implies T_1(v)=0,T_2(w)=0\implies 0$ is an eigen value of both $T_1,T_2$ which is false because minimal polynomials of both $T_1,T_2$ don't have $0$ as their root.

Hence $\text{nullity} (T)=0$.

But I am unable to prove that $\deg f(x)=5$.
Please help me out here.